# Error Installing Gitosis on Fedora Core

Tags: python, linux, git, fedora, gitosis

I'm trying to follow these instructions on installing gitosis:

http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

and these:

http://www.webtop.com.au/installing-git-and-gitosis-on-fedora-10

And at the point where I need to clone the gitosis-admin.git repository from the server I'm setting up, I am receiving this error:

```
ERROR:gitosis.app:Unable to read config file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/git/.gitosis.conf'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have followed every set of instructions imaginable at this point, and I can't seem to find anyone else who has received this error. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Dave Morris

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running that command as the git user, and make sure that the git user owns the /home/git directory.

Are you running *git clone **git**@yourserver:gitosis-admin.git* ?

It sounds like one of those things is not the case.

Comment: I am running git clone git@yourserver:gitosis-admin.git, and the git user was created using "useradd git". Wouldn't that make it the owner of its own home directory?

Comment: Here is the output of "ls -al /home":

[root@git01 gitosis]# ls -al /home/
drwx------  7 git      git      4096 2010-01-20 21:34 git

Comment: Hmm, strange, could it be that .gitosis.conf either isn't there or has the wrong permissions? What does `ls -al /home/git` give you?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 git  git    53 2010-01-20 21:06 .gitosis.conf -> /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/gitosis.conf

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git ?